# How can I increase the animation delay of li elements by an increasing amount with a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, css-animations

Suppose I have some number of list elements and I want them to fade in by an increasingly delayed amount. I can do that using the css below. However, it is long and bulky. How can I convert the increases in the animation delay with a for loop in javascript?

**html**:

```
<li> First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
<li>Fifth</li>
```

**css:**

```css
  li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.9s 1;
  animation: fadeIn 0.9s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

li:nth-child(5n+2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
  animation-delay: 1.0s;
}

li:nth-child(5n+3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

li:nth-child(5n+4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s;
  animation-delay: 2.0s;
}

li:nth-child(5n+5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}


/* Animation steps */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

**attempted javascript**:

```
for (var i in ul) {
  li.style.animationDelay += '0.5*i'+'s';
}
```

Comment: Not seeing the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce what you've made - there's no HTML, your CSS is missing the keyframe animation and your JS is outside the snippet. If you can make a reproducible snippet here we could help. Also not seeing the link to Philipp's example that you're talking about.

Comment: @JonUleis is this better? It's a little different than before, but more towards the central issue I was having.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the `5n+x` formulas, rather than `nth-child(1)`, `nth-child(2)`, etc?

Comment: Well I suppose that could work, but I wanted the user to have the ability to add new list items and I guess I figured n could be incremented with javascript?

Comment: @JonUleis is my question clear though? Have I provided enough information for you to reproduce the issue?